# Como comparar vários termos diferentes de maneira simplificada em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu queria saber como mostrar que vários termos são diferentes de um outro termo, sem ter que ficar repetindo ? Como no exemplo:

```
if termo1 != valor_aleatorio and termo2 != valor_aleatorio and termo3 != valor_aleatorio:
```

Eu tentei de algumas formas, mas deram erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é fazer um [teste de pertinência](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations), o que nos deixa duas possibilidades:

```
if valor_aleatorio not in (termo1, termo2, termo3):
```

No caso acima é verificado se o valor da variável `valor_aleatorio` não está presente na [tupla](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) `(termo1, termo2, termo3)`.

---

```
if valor_aleatorio in (termo1, termo2, termo3):
```

Nesse último caso é verificado se o valor da variável `valor_aleatorio` está presente na tupla `(termo1, termo2, termo3)`.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar `all`:

```
if all(termo != valor_aleatorio for termo in (termo1, termo2, termo3)):
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu para entender a lógica.